# User job not enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, unicorn, upstart

i have a codestains.conf file in ~/.init folder

```
    description "Codestains"
    author "Varun Mundra"

    start on virtual-filesystems
    stop on runlevel [06]

    env PATH=/opt/www/codestains.com/current/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/us$

    env RAILS_ENV=production
    env RACK_ENV=production

    setuid ubuntu
    setgid sudo

    chdir /opt/www/codestains.com

    pre-start script
      exec >/home/ubuntu/codestains.log 2>&1
      exec /opt/www/codestains.com/current/bin/unicorn -D -c /opt/www/codestains.com/current/config/unicorn.rb $
    end script

    post-stop script
      exec kill 'cat /tmp/unicorn.codestains.pid'
    end script
```

I have added https://gist.github.com/bradleyayers/1660182 in /etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf` to enable Upstart user jobs
But everytime I run

```
    start codestains
    sudo start codestains
```

I get  "start: Unknown job: codestains".
I have tried a lot of things available online. Nothing seems to help.

Also,

```
    init-checkconf codestains.conf
```

gives "File codestains.conf: syntax ok"

Answer (score 0):

I spot one error that is certainly a problem; I do not know if it is the only problem. I haven't made any attempt to test it. However, this bit:

`exec kill 'cat /tmp/unicorn.codestains.pid'`

is definitely wrong, it would pass the string `cat /tmp/unicorn.codestains.pid` to the `kill` command, which will not do what you want.

You may have seen an example, and missed that they are backtick characters, which causes the shell to execute `cat /tmp/unicorn.codestains.pid`, capture its `STDOUT`, and then interpolate the result where you put the backticks; IOW it passes the contents of that pid file to the `kill` command.

Like this:

`` exec kill `cat /tmp/unicorn.codestains.pid` ``

Note the subtly different [backtick character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

Which shells (bash, at least) will treat specially as I described: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html
(see the section on "Command substitution")

HTH